# Advice on postgreSQL table logging

Tags: postgresql-performance, write-ahead-logging

I am thinking I can turn off logging for certain tables in my PostgreSQL analytic data warehouse.  There are a core set of very large tables (between 50 and 500Gb) that are completely rebuilt at the start of each month.  Each table is truncated, identity reset, indexes removed, then reloaded, then reindexed. Once reloaded, the tables are permissioned to select-only and don't get any updates or inserts.  Is there any reason for these tables to use the WAL?  I should get a performance benefit for the monthly reloads if I turn logging off, and we're not using replication, but I've never used this table option before and want to be sure I'm not missing something important.

Comment: Are you OK with rebuilding these very large tables again on the 2nd of the month if your system crashes?

Comment: @mustaccio -- I've been working with several dozen production PG systems for ten years and I've seen one full system crash, so my sense of the risk is low. It seems like a good trade-off,  but your point is well taken -- that's up to the users.  I'll be sure to provide an assessment of how much this may shorten monthly down-time assuming no crashes, as well as how long it could increase downtime in the event of a crash.

Comment: " I've seen one full system crash, so my sense of the risk is low" -- unfortunately, this is a very common fallacy.

Comment: @mustaccio - why is it a fallacy? Effort should be expended according to risk (with stakeholder input).

Comment: @Vérace: "No Boom today.  Boom tomorrow.  There's always a Boom tomorrow".  Just because it hasn't happened yet doesn't mean it won't.  As a DBA, you /need/ this kind of attitude.  For us, losing Data is a capital offence.  
You don't say how long this rebuild takes.  Minutes?  No problem.  Hours?  Days?  Adding that on /after/ recovering a crashed database might not go down well with the Business - make sure they've signed off on this.  Or, perhaps better, offload this "reference" data to another database and query it "remotely" (Foreign Data Wrapper).

Comment: "why is it a fallacy?" -- because human intuition about risk is well known to be flawed. Everything **will** fail, we just don't know when; if you act on the assumption that your system or process will **not** fail, pain and suffering are inevitable.